# VueJS: Using A Loading Icon When Waiting For Results Of Asynchronous Database Calls

Tags: vue.js

I wonder where and how to setup a loading icon in VueJS, when the data my site depends on, isn't ready.

Do you know how to do this?

Would be nice and helpful.

Comment: Check out my answer here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/44737095/7814783) . There is even an example fiddle

Comment: you should start with what you tried and how you are currently loading your data. post an example

Answer (score 4):

Considering you are using axios which is currently the most used http client for vue.js you would do something like

```
data: function() {
  return { results: [], loading: true};
}
```

And now let's say you load on create

```
created: function() {
  axios.get('/path/to/my/data/endpoint')
    .then(function(response) {
      this.result = response.data;
      this.loading = false;
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function() {
      this.loading = false;
    }.bind(this));
}
```

And in your template you have something like

```
<img src="/path/to/my/loading/icon" v-if="loading" />

<ul v-else>
  <li v-for="result in results"> ... </li>
</ul>
```